# Valid Singaporean visa in an expired passport

Tags: visas, passports, singapore

I got a valid Singaporean visa in my old passport which expired recently. This is usually ok and I have been through it before but in other countries.

Just to make sure can I go to Singapore with my new passport while having the old passport with the valid visa in it? I can't seem to find a resource that confirms this.

Comment: Is it a re-entry permit for permanent resident? In that case question 4 on [this ICA page](http://www.ifaq.gov.sg/ICA/apps/fcd_faqmain.aspx?qst=hRhkP9BzcBImsx2TBbssMsxu7lqt6UJK70a1wAEVmyc%2fWgJYcbDMub4Q1j7gA3%2b6KX0GNv9gxsfSQTt%2bFtQ59pJzpOb%2fwy0sRZ8lw5YUXDNyqkFPYJzL6y009293iXOym5dx6HT%2byvTs9IbmcTt2P9YgaFbasEwcz15D4S3M5H%2fOvJQ%2f6NK2UROR%2b52jezTk1eziqxvcxPeramLO5Bzm1g5awE3QVsdw8RzNCW%2fWmqw%3d#TOPIC_5206) answers your question.

Comment: also see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23997/can-i-travel-to-singapore-on-a-visa-with-old-passport-number

Comment: For Singapore, there is a visa and a visit pass.  I believe you need to get a new visa each time unless you have a long-term visitor pass

Answer (score 4):

In general visas are still valid if the passport is expired and you travel with both passports (the old one with the visa and the new one).

This is very common with multiple entry visa, but the visa on the old passport should not be invalidated (as the other pages of your old passport got a "no valid" stamp).

You should contact the nearest Singapore embassy/consulate to get confirmation that your visa is still valid.

Comment: Thank you, but this is does not answer my question. I know that this is the usual case.. but Singapore is a bit tough when it comes to visas hence I wanted an official resource that confirms this.. I know I can call the embassy but I am trying to avoid this as of now.

Comment: The edit you have added then removed answers my question actually.. you should add it again.

Comment: I removed because it was referred to Japanese visa, not Singaporean

Comment: Didn't notice that.. I thought it is for Singapore embassy in Japan but its the other way around...