# I have a new passport, my valid visa has the old passport number. Can I still travel?

Tags: visas, passport-renewals

I am holding a valid Singapore visa, but I have obtained new passport as the old one was full. I would like to travel Singapore in couple of days. Can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to Singapore on a visa with old passport number?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23997/can-i-travel-to-singapore-on-a-visa-with-old-passport-number)

Comment: @traveller In that question, OP has **lost** their old passport.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that they will accept if you bring the old passport along. But need a confirmation from ICA.

Comment: @MJeffryes Agreed - but the answer also covers travelling with both old and new passports, and transferring the visa, although admittedly that’s likely not possible in the timeframe.

Comment: @traveller If the question is different, it isn’t a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

From the embassy website

> **I have an existing visa, but had just changed my passport. Can I
>   extend my visa?**
>
> We do not do extension of visa. However, we can transfer your current
>   visa from your old passport to your new passport. Please send both
>   your original old and new passports (including current Singapore
>   Visa), Form 14A application form, Australian contact details and a
>   self-addressed envelope to the Singapore High Commission.
>
> There is no fee charged for the transfer of visa to your new passport.

https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/canberra/visa_information/faq_new.html

I think its not possible in a couple of days. However, you can call Immigration and Checkpoints Authority of Singapore in below URL to see if its allowed.

https://www.ica.gov.sg/contact-us

Comment: Where to submit the passports varies by country. You've quoted information for Australia. The OP is probably not in Australia and should check the Singapore embassy website for the country where he lives.